# FindParentWindow(this).Name returns null

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a usercontrol that is a footer for my application windows. I am trying to get the name of the Window that is currently hosting the usercontrol, which by the way is several elements deep so I cannot just call its parent.

I have read about the VisualTreeHelper and I have even tried several different code samples like the one below but no matter what I do I get **An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in xxxx.exe but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
public partial class ucFooter : UserControl
{
    public ucFooter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tbParent.Text = FindParentWindow(this).Name;
    }

    private static Window FindParentWindow(DependencyObject child)
    {
        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

        //CHeck if this is the end of the tree
        if (parent == null) return null;

        Window parentWindow = parent as Window;
        if (parentWindow != null)
        {
            return parentWindow;
        }
        else
        {
            //use recursion until it reaches a Window
            return FindParentWindow(parent);
        }
    }  
}
```

Stepping through the code it never gets passed the If Parent == null check. So I have two questions. What needs to be modified to make this work and why does it think the parent is null when it is not?

Comment: `if (parent == null) return null;` - don't you mean `return child` because with `null`, `FindParentWindow(this).Name` will blow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During execution of the control's constructor the visual tree is not yet established. Move the call of the method to a `Loaded` event handler:

```
public ucFooter()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tbParent.Text = FindParentWindow(this).Name;
}

private static Window FindParentWindow(DependencyObject child)
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

    if (parent == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return (parent as Window) ?? FindParentWindow(parent);
}
```

Comment: As a side note it's worth noting that instead of writing your own `FindParentWindow` there is already a method that does exactly that [`Window.GetWindow(this)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.getwindow(v=vs.110).aspx) assuming tree is already loaded of course